# Why doesn't cluster autoscaler work on AWS EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, autoscaling, amazon-eks

I had numerous deployment issues with getting the kubernetes cluster-autoscaler working on AWS EKS. At length, I got it working.

Notes:

- don't use the helm chart.
- Refer to their version chart [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler#releases)
- Based on your version of kubernetes, you'll need to go to that branch of their code. WARN: their "version" does NOT necessarily line up with the container version being deployed.

  - In my case, I was deploying the latest on EKS, which is presently K8s 1.11.X, thus I need their [1.3.X branch](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/cluster-autoscaler-release-1.3/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws)
- Now RTFM, but here are the other gotchas.
- The examples in their AWS directory don't assume you're using EKS, which deploys on AMZN2 linux by default. You'll have to update the manifest as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws#common-notes-and-gotchas) to use the appropriate SSL directories
- The example in their AWS directory assumes the `us-east-1` region for you. You're probably not using it, and it's not a variable. Update that manifest, round 2.
- This was my biggest gotcha, and it was a problem of my own creation. Make sure your aws-auth config has the latest IAM role in it, if you've torn down / recreated your EKS cluster. Otherwise literally -nothing- will be able to auth to the K8s APIServer, including your nodes.

Errors I ran into:

Error: 
`1 static_autoscaler.go:118] Failed to update node registry: RequestError: send request failed caused by: Post https://autoscaling.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup autoscaling.us-west-2a.amazonaws.com on RE.DA.CT.ED:53: no such host`

Solution: wrong region in default manifest

Error: 
`container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/60c34f52ad1e6f0e3368d95794c71036fc465707f8ef3247032b6291e71d9331/merged\\\" at \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/60c34f52ad1e6f0e3368d95794c71036fc465707f8ef3247032b6291e71d9331/merged/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt\\\" caused \\\"not a directory\\\"\""`

Solution: `%s/ca\-certificates\.crt/ca\-bundle\.crt/g`

Comment: I am running into an error whcih says:                                                                                         Failed to create AWS Manager: cannot autodiscover ASGs: WebIdentityErr: failed to retrieve credentials
caused by: InvalidIdentityToken: Incorrect token audience                                                                                   Do you have any idea on this?The role associated has administrators access and OIDC is issued as well.
        status code: 400, request id: 8d525f32-b8e0-4651-9ab8-7afabec3e451